How to know if an open-source implementation used for research and extended by the researchers with new code, does not infringe a patent?
How to know (beforehand) if an open-source implementation/code in a public repository with the source code available to the public, which is used for research and extended by the researchers with new code, targeting a journal/paper with experiments, does not infringe a patent?

By "the researchers", do you mean yourselves or someone else?

Hire a parent lawyer to do a search for you. Be prepared to pay $$$.

IANAL, but "open source" and "patented" are inconsistent. They are at the opposite ends of the rules about intellectual property, though trade secrets might figure on that scale as well.
If it is specifically (and validly) open source, presumably with a permissive license, then you can use it within limits of that license. If it is patented then, for the terms of the patent, you may not without specific permission of the patent holder.
Software bound by patent should be tagged as such by the patent holder, just as open source software normally has a specific license (unless it is public domain with no claimed copyright). But the notice of a patent might not be within the source of the software itself (yes, strange), but listed elsewhere by the company.
Patent holders are permitted to give licenses on their "devices" to groups or individuals, either for free or with a cost, but they still aren't "open source".
However, an "extension" done by others than yourselves may have a separate license, or even be itself patented, but it would only be the extension to which such a restriction would apply and any restriction would need to be consistent with the original license.
NOTE: Patent law applied to software especially varies and IIRC is in a state of flux. "Devices" are patentable, and not all software meets the criteria of a "device". A web search will tell you more. See Wikipedia for example.
NOTE also, that a given piece of software might be open source in one jurisdiction and patented in another. My guess is that this is disappearing and is an historical artifact. Some early software patents have or will soon expire.

Open source and patented are not nessicarly opposed. Many open source licenses do not include patent grants, and the variations between jurisdictions and the fact independent origination does not protect against patents means there is a nontrivail amount of opensource software out there restrictions by patents.

Libmpeg2 is a classic example. It's open source (gpl) however the mpeg licensing authority (who have no relation to the lib authors) went after multiple company's who used it in there products for violating the mpeg patents.

@user1937198, that seems to confuse 'open source' with 'unwarranted claims of open source'. Either the patent or the license is invalid.

It's a three party situation.  Party one develops the code and offers it with no restrictions incompatable with open source. Party two receives it and uses it. Party three sues two for infringing their patent. Did Party one not open source it?

@user1937198, unlike copyright, which is automatic (most places), patents need to be applied for and granted by government bodies. You seem to be confusing patent with copyright.

I am not. Software patents need to be applied for and granted. And which point they apply to any use of any software that performs the process of that patent, regardless of if anyone involved in that software has any awareness, knowledge or understanding of the patent. As such, there a numerous cases of well intended open source developers building software to open source goals, that fit into patents already granted that they were not able to research or understand.

@user1937198, one can't claim that a patented item is open source and make it so. If you hold title to a yacht, I can't claim that it is mine (or free for anyone to use).

It comes down to what one means by 'owning' the software. At least conventionally, having a patent doesn't imply that you 'own' the software, that is usually only used to mean copyright rights, due to the issue of a patent holder a) getting patent rights over anything anyone else writes that fulfills the same spec. They own the algorithm, not the software implementation. And b) those rights being on a very different timescale and jurisdictional scope to copyright rights. So I don't think it's clear to make analogy to a yacht due to the different nature's of the rights.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Buffy For the Libmpeg2 example, I could have gone and purchased the necessary patent licenses, then I can incorporate the open source library in my software. Open source licenses can have nothing to say about patent rights, e.g. the BSD license.

The two statuses 'open/closed source' and 'patented/unpatented' have fundamentally nothing to do with each other, other than that they are (in different ways) factors that can have a bearing on questions of freedom to use some particular subject-matter. (With all due respect to @Buffy here.)
As has already been indicated, patenting is a highly formalized and institutionalized process with a specific legal regime. It involves making an application to one or more patent granting authorities, which can lead (usually after much effort) to grants of patent rights limited by subject-matter, geographical area and term.  In principle that is independent of the existence (or not) of any other kinds of rights.
By contrast, there does not need to be anything formalized about open- or closed-source materials (often software codes, of course). If the originator/owner makes or allows some content to become publicly known, then to that extent it might be called open or open-source. But publishing something does not in itself entail giving up existing patent rights or copyrights (for example). [One must of course beware, before making public releases, of any risks of giving up eligibility for rights not yet applied for.]  There is nothing at all contradictory about having something publicly known, and it being the subject of patent rights or copyrights -- among other kinds of rights.
@Dan Romik's comment is fair enough and appropriate, it's often thought wise to check the existence or non-existence of patent rights by going through a patent lawyer, which can indeed be expensive. One might choose in the first place a patent information specialist, for a preliminary winnowing to see if there is any possibility of a legal issue to take to a lawyer, or any obvious way to limit or circumscribe such issues.
I'd also suggest (on the basis of professional experience, but also  making clear that I'm nobody's lawyer!) that in practice, the participants in a piece of research that has created something useful are often in the best position to know the literature, or get to know it if they haven't yet done that. They, perhaps more than anyone else, often know how and where to sniff out any possibly competing or interfering subject matter.  And nowadays it's not that difficult to extend literature-searches into patent searches, using such tools as those at the US patent & trademark office (https://www.uspto.gov/patents/search) and the European patent office tools at (https://worldwide.espacenet.com/). But it does take some effort, and the people concerned sometimes need persuasion to see that the effort is something necessary, and actually expend some of their energies on it.  Then the results may usually give a well-informed idea of whether there is any possible legal issue on which consultation is needed. At the very least, a well-conducted search can raise the effectiveness and reduce the costs of any later legal consultations found to be necessary.

Conventionally, open-source, implies a copyleft or permissive with redistribution copyright license. Open-source has become a term of art in the industry with respect to copyright licensing. Simply publishing the source without granting redistribution and modification rights is more typically known as source-available and would be controversial to advertise as open source.

https://opensource.org/osd spells out the usual requirements to be considered open source and not just source available.

@user1937198 -- But the documents you cite are guidelines, not laws. They don't address the point that fundamentally the legal regime of patents and the (non-binding) conventions of open source make for two statuses that have nothing to do with each other.

They describe the conventional meaning of the words. Just making something publicly available is not open sourcing it. Open sourcing it implies an intent by the author to allow free redistribution and modification. Classic examples of software that had publicly avaliable source but where not open source include the IBM BIOS. Which is different from what you said. And for patents this implies that ideally anyone who contributed also licenses their own patents that are relevant.
